# Getting info on other apps via Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is it possible via objective-c to find information (such as the names) for other apps installed on an iPhone from my app?

Comment: I read that sentence 5 times and I still have no idea what the hell you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean, find out what other apps are installed? Yes there's a way, I'm not quite sure of it, but if you keep that title you sure won't get much help.

Comment: I think the question asked is: "I want to index all of the applications installed on the iPhone. Is there a function that gives me the names of the installed applications?"

Comment: OP: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I really disagree with that link. It advocates treating people as stupid if they ask elementary questions (which the SO FAQ specifically allows), and it was also more geared towards a forum/mailing list.

Comment: Moreover, if the questions that that link classifies as being "too dumb and needs more work" were removed from here and/or superuser, you'd lose a good chunk of the site(s). I quote Jeff atwood (in a comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806704/3-d-game-programming/1806720#1806720): "it is our policy to give reasonable answers even when the question is crazy. That's just how we roll.".  That's not to say this question couldnt have used more work i just think the tone of that article is a little dated and harsh.

Comment: @RCIX: Fair enough about the tone. Not good advice for answerers, but it has good advice for askers.

Comment: @RCIX - I agree. In particular, I don't know why people keep paying attention to Eric Raymond's writings. He has very limited real geek cred. All he does is write in an overly authoritative tone about his experience, but his own accomplishments in software are rather limited. He's had some notable public failures due to his arrogance (Remember when he tried to replace the Linux build system? The kernel people didn't want his crap, but that didn't stop him from writing like it was the One True Replacement for "make config".) Not to mention he injects libertarian politics into the jargon file.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a "legal" way to do this and get the app in the AppStore, then **no**, Apple does not provide such an API.  And they probably never will, because this will go against the users' privacy.